# scala constructor can't use implicit function & initialize class

Tags: scala, constructor, implicit

I have a constructor:

```
  import ****.Views._
  def this(stages: Seq[PipelineStage]) = this (
    stages,
    new TraversableView(stages).filterByType[Producer].map(_.getOutputCol).toList,
    new TraversableView(stages).filterByType[Producer].map(_.getOutputCol).lastOption)
  )
```

The TraversableView is an immplicit function under Views:

```
  implicit class TraversableView[A](self: Traversable[A]) {

    def filterByType[B <: A: ClassTag]: Traversable[B] = {
      val result: Traversable[B] = self.flatMap{
        case tt: B => Some(tt)
        case _ => None
      }
      result
    }
  }
```

However when I compile, I got the following error:

```
Error:(25, 9) not found: type TraversableView
    new TraversableView(stages).filterByType[Producer].map(_.getOutputCol).toList,
        ^
Error:(26, 9) not found: type TraversableView
    new TraversableView(stages).filterByType[Producer].map(_.getOutputCol).lastOption
        ^
```

How could this happen? Is it a limitation of scala compiler?